# How to request data in symfony using $request

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony by default named form fields this way: entity[fiel].
So, i am trying to request a submites value using request as below:

```
HTML
<input type="text" id="turma_nome" name="turma[nome]" required="required" maxlength="10">

PHP
$request->get('turma[nome]')
```

But it doesn't work.
How can i request do it please?

Comment: How are you sending request (`<input type="text" name="user">`) from html form (share code)? Also, print `$request->query->get('user')` to see what is the output? Refer to https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object

Comment: i send and request as above.

Comment: `$request->query->get('turma')` should print an associative array. then you can access key `nome` on it.

Comment: i tried, but don´t return an associative array!

Comment: what does it print?

Comment: unfortunately nothing

Comment: check output of `$request->all()`

Comment: i am so grateful!!!!
you helped me a lot

Comment: i did as you suggested, but this way: $request->request->all()

Comment: pleasure helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using POST to send the data.

`$request->query->get()` works only for GET parameters.

You need to use `$request->request->get()` instead to get the POST parameters.

Comment: I tried $request->get('turma[nome]'), $request->request->get('turma[nome]') and $request->query->get('turma[nome]') but none work.

Answer (score 0):

furtunately i fixed it!

Symfony by default named form fields this way: entity[fiel].

to get this value using $request, we got do:

$request->get('entity')['field']

Att: the form method is POST

I am so grateful for those that helped me fixed it!!